# How to run an ionic app with mongodb data?

Tags: javascript, android, mongodb, ionic-framework

I am developing an ionic app using mongodb as database. The problem is when I test my app in a browser I can see the data, but when I run it on a physical device the data doesn't display. I tried to inspect it so I found this error message:

[image]

Here is the mongod.cfg file:

[image]

Can you help me?

Comment: `localhost` refers to the current machine. You'll need your local IP address to access it from another device.

Answer (score 0):

From a mobile device you cant access `localhost` because it refers the current machine.

You can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) for exposing your local web server. After that you just need to replace the `http://localhost:3001/` with the ngrok url for testing on you mobile device.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i tried the IP address i found in ngrok but it didn't work.
I found that I must Allow Remote Connections to MongoDB but I don't know how to do that, can you help me in this?

Comment: I think you need to comment the `net.bindIp` option in `mongod.conf` and then restart the `mongod`service

Comment: I added the mongod.cfg file please check it, I'm realy new to mongodb.

Comment: Do you have the port 27017 open on your Firewall?

Comment: I opened the port but when I tried to run npm start it said: " MongoNetworkError: connection 0 to 192.168.1.51:27017 closed" however mongo server is open on the same port